# Find all files modified by a specific user

Tags: files

On Ubuntu, is it possible to generate a list of all files in the /home folder that were modified by a specific user? I want to find a list of all of the files that I have created or modified since I installed Ubuntu 12.04.

I mainly want to do this so that I can find all the files that I have created or modified, and then move them to my other Ubuntu installation.

Comment: There is no reliable way to do so in Linux. Please check this thread: https://serverfault.com/questions/97831/who-last-modified-file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use find

```
find /home -user $USER -mtime -90
```

The -mtime is the number of days, so -90 is the last 90 days. Adjust the number of says as needed.

See also http://content.hccfl.edu/pollock/unix/findcmd.htm

It may just be easier to copy all of home, `cp -Ra home` or use rsync

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/rsync

Comment: Is it possible to exclude specific folders from this query (so that things like browser cache data can be excluded)?

Comment: Yes, use `-prune` , see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4210042/exclude-directory-from-find-command

Comment: This command will merely show the files owned by a specific user. There is no reliable way to determine who created or modified a file in Linux. Linux does not track file changes.